# Tabla html me da fecha que no tengo

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tengo una `tabla` en una vista que obtengo registros del `model` y en una columna que recientemente añadí de tipo `Date`.

Hice un registro para comprobar sí había guardado bien (Cosa que si confirmo), pero cuando muestro esta fecha en la tabla de la vista, me lo muestra como `01/01/0001 12:00:00 a. m.` cosa que en mi base de datos lo tengo como `2023-01-15 00:00:00.0000000`.

Aquí tengo el model de la variable.

```
[Display(Name = "Fecha de Vencimiento")]
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public DateTime FechaVencimiento { get; set; }
```

Y pues en la vista es una `tabla` y dentro del `tbody` tengo el `foreach` iterando todo los registros.

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
 {
   <td>
      @item.FechaVencimiento
   </td>
 }
```

No pongo todos los otros campos por qué en realidad, solo este me falla.

Así es como me lo muestra, la primera posición debería de ser 15 de Enero y las demás vacías por qué están `null`.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Luisito, hermano, revisa la documentación de los valores por defecto de un DateTime.